# Android TV Emulator: How to create curved display emulator?

Tags: android, emulation, android-tv

Android studio default TV emulator comes with two different regulations and sizes. But now some android TVs are curved displayed and with different resolutions.
Is it possible to make the Android emulator screen curved?
Or, is there any other platform available where can support curved TV?

Answer (score -1):

Curved display is not different from flat display to my knowledge. You don't need to add extra support for it.

If you want to change resolution for your emulator then go to `Tools - ADV Manager - Create Virtual Device - New Hardware Profile`. From there you can select Android TV device type and set custom screen resolution

Comment: Already some of the customer fetch issues,  the content is corp on edge. It's not about the resolution it's about UI/UX test.

Comment: I will repeat myself - curved displays are not different from flat displays. Because of this - there is no way you can make screen curved. So your customers facing problems because of other issue.